# await on UserManager causes the error A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

**BACKGROUND**

I am working on a **.Net Core API** to drive a lyrics application. Users can sign up, submit artists & lyrics, and earn kudos / XP points in the process. Basically a community-driven lyrics website.

**CODE**

Here's my ArtistController class:

```
[Route("api/artists")]
public class ArtistsController : Controller
{
  private readonly IPermissionsService _permissionsService;
  private readonly IArtistsService _artistsService;

  public ArtistsController(IArtistsService artistsService, IPermissionsService permissionsService)
  {
    _permissionsService = permissionsService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(permissionsService));
    _artistsService = artistsService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(artistsService));
  }

  [HttpGet("{slug}")]
  [HttpGet("{slug}/lyrics", Name = "GetArtist")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetArtist(string slug)
  {
    if (!_artistsService.ArtistExists(slug)) return NotFound();
    var permissions = await _permissionsService.GetPermissions(HttpContext);
    var artist = _artistsService.GetArtistBySlug(slug, permissions.UserId, permissions.IsAdministrator);
    if (artist == null) return NotFound();
    return Ok(artist);
  }

  // other methods omitted
}
```

In the spirit of testability, I created an `IPermissionsService`, this way when I come to Unit Test the controller, I can easily do so without worrying about `HttpContext` and `User`.

Here is the code for `PermissionsService` class:

```
public class PermissionsService : IPermissionsService
{
  private string _userId;
  private bool _isAdministrator;
  private HttpContext _httpContext;
  private readonly UserManager<BbUser> _userManager;

  public PermissionsService(UserManager<BbUser> userManager)
  {
    _userManager = userManager;
  }

  public async Task<Permissions> GetPermissions(HttpContext httpContext)
  {
    _httpContext = httpContext;
    PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag();
    var permissions = new Permissions
    {
      UserId = _userId,
      IsAdministrator = _isAdministrator
    };

    return await Task.Run(() => permissions);
  }

  private async void PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag()
  {
    if (!IsAuthenticated()) return;
    var username = _httpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    _userId = user.Id;
    _isAdministrator = roles.Contains("Admin");
  }

  private bool IsAuthenticated()
  {
    return _httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

**PROBLEM**

When I run the API and attempt to call that end-point. I get the following error:

> A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

The message is pretty clear, but I am not sure how to overcome this error. Before moving that logic out to the `PermissionsService` I was not getting the error and all was working fine!

Comment: FYI: instead of `await Task.Run(() => permissions);`, you can use `await Task.FromResult(permissions);`

Comment: Is one better than the other?

Comment: `Task.FromResult` immediately creates a `Task` object that's completed, thus it doesn't need to create a new thread, so yes, it's better (in this case). Doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Methods that do `async` work should return `Task` and not `void` unless they are event handlers. This will allow the resulting `Task` to be awaited. Because `PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag` is not awaited you are making calls to the same `DbContext` instance simultaneously across threads. If you follow the call stack:

1. Code enters `GetPermissions`
2. You start work in `PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag` *but do not wait for it to be completed*
3. Code immediately returns from `GetPermissions` (*code in `PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag` is also still executing*)
4. Code continues and calls method on `_artistsService`

This can result in the DbContext being called by multiple threads at the same time which causes your exception.

Fix the code so that the result of `PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag` is awaited.

- Change your code to await the `PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag` method so it returns type `Task`
- await the result of `PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag`
- Wrapping the result in a `Task` is no longer necessary at the end of `GetPermissions`
- I also recommend renaming it and adding the suffix `Async` as this is considered proper naming convention for methods that return type `Task`. That would result in methods named `GetPermissionsAsync` and `PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlagAsync`

Changed code:

```
public async Task<Permissions> GetPermissions(HttpContext httpContext)
{
    _httpContext = httpContext;
    // await result
    await PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag();
    var permissions = new Permissions
    {
      UserId = _userId,
      IsAdministrator = _isAdministrator
    };

    // wrapping the result in Task is no longer necessary 
    return permissions;
}

// change void to Task
private async Task PopulateUserIdAndIsAdminFlag()
{
    if (!IsAuthenticated()) return;
    var username = _httpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    _userId = user.Id;
    _isAdministrator = roles.Contains("Admin");
}
```